# Can't Read Value From My PLC ( s71200 ) using S7.NetPlus Library

Tags: .net, plc

I want to read DataBlocks of PLC using .net as in explained in here ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tYTjNG8YL-c ).
Everything seems normal and working while using PLCSIM (NetToPLCSim).

But when I try to connect my PLC S7 PLC DataBlocks, it gives "WrongVariableFormat" for instance address of (DB2.DBX0.0), but in simulation mode, I can access and read the value of this address.

I made this configuration but it didn't solve my issue.

1. Optimized block access disabled
2. Protection - Full Access Protection
3. Permit Access with PUT/GET from remote partner.

My PLC is S71200, I am using TIA Portal V16, S7.Net Plus v0.14.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please can you post your code? I worked with S7.Net previously.

Answer (score 0):

You've probably already found the solution, but in case anyone else is looking for it:
I encountered the exact same issue. It is necessary to load the entire hardware configuration onto the PLC, rather than just the program. This will refresh the PLC's security access settings (PUT/GET communication...)